# Should we merge the tags 'bank' and 'banking'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should we merge the tags [bank](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank) and [banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banking)?  I think they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea -- merged all the suggestions and set up a synonym between [banks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banks) → [banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banking), too.

Answer (score 3):

Merge them, and grab [banks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banks) on the way, which only has four questions right now. It's possible to distinguish between [bank](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank) and [banking](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banking), but the actual questions are not cleanly separated.